# Perl WWW::Mechanize::Firefox and input type file

Tags: perl, mechanize, www-mechanize

Cross-post http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=981067

I have a problem using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox to upload a file to a site with a form using an input type file, like this :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST" id="formular">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="image0" type="file" id="image0"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
```

The content of uploader.php is the following :

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['image0']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image0']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['image0']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file,".  basename( $_FILES['image0']['name'])." please try again!";
}
?>
```

And the code I use for uploading the file is the following :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $bot = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new( autoclose => 0,activate =>1);

$bot->get('http://127.0.0.1/file/index.html');
$bot->form_id('formular');
$bot->field('image0','IMAGE.JPG');
$bot->submit;
```

There is no error at execution, and the form is submited but without nothing in image0.

The version of WWW::Mechanize::Firefox I use is 0.66 my perl version is : v5.10.0 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

Thanks

Comment: Is there a file `IMAGE.JPG` in your current working directory? Maybe the filename is not in uppercase?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try adding the whole path to the image file and a key/value pair in the `field()` method something like

```
my $image_path = "/home/images/IMAGE.JPG";
$bot->field(image0=>$image_path);
$bot->submit();
```

Also, assuming that `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` inherits all of `LWP::UserAgents` methods, include the code below just before the `$bot->submit();`

```
$bot->add_handler("request_send",  sub { shift->dump; return });
$bot->add_handler("response_done", sub { shift->dump; return });
```

This will enable logging in your code. Keep an eye on the Request and response codes in the log file something like 'HTTP 200 OK' or 'HTTP 302 Found'. These are standard HTTP response codes so you'll know that you are getting the correct responses back.